# How to create and send an HTML formatted eMail using CSS?

Tags: users, emails, theming

I am going crazy in making a welcome eMail in Drupal.

What I want is sending a nicely formatted eMail using HTML and CSS. I do not need to send an eMail to user except a welcome eMail after user registration, that's all.

I've tested my code in eMail field in the "**Home » Administration » Configuration » People**" page, but it does not accept CSS code.

HTML email and mail system modules are so sophisticated that I could not use theme.

Anybody a solution for this?

Comment: Just you wait... I'm creating a Drupal.org project for you!

Answer (score 2):

With some experience in that field I must say designing 'nice' html mail templates can be difficult – no matter what system you use to actually send your mail. The reason for this is that there are quite many different email clients – from full blown local desktop computer programms to mobile apps on smart phones and feature phones – and a virtally countless number of online services –– all behaving slightly different. Some email clients do accept css3, some don't interprete css at all, some only accept inline css.

So I suppose you probably either have to start digging into that – or use the methods that are rather 'safe' to use as offered by various services and/or modules.

Answer (score 0):

The [MimeMail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) module is pretty good with this. Try that and use the table [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) to reference what syntax/tags are available for the best cross-client support.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all
I used mime mail and display suit module and it worked fine for me. that was what I need

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: ok. indeed it was another answer! I add display suit module and that was the reason why it works.

Comment: Well, if you're not using any of the *other* answers, why do you say "Thanks"?  Doing so are a sure way to confuse reviewers.

Comment: @shekoufeh Can you elaborate on why/how DS was needed here?  Right now, this answer won't really help future readers.

Comment: sure! I used html email and DS module. in html email I choose display suit code as Post-filtering under step 3. then I wrote my email text with html and inline css in admin/config/people/accounts! that was all.